# How to use a javascript Regex to globally find and replace the beginning of a string from a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I am trying to replace any non encoded ampersands in a string in JavaScript and was wondering if this was possible. I have the regex build to detect this in the string, but when I do a replace, I will lose the parameter name.

Current input:

```
http://www.somesite.com/id/2343?paramA=1&paramB=asdf
```

From a textarea

```
<textarea id='test-box'>http://www.somesite.com/id/2343?paramA=1&paramB=asdf</textarea>

var str   = $('#test-box').val();;
var regex = /&[a-z]+=/gi;
str = str.replace(regex, [REPLACE &'s WITH &amp;'s]);
console.log(str);
```

Desired output:

```
http://www.somesite.com/id/2343?paramA=1&amp;paramB=asdf
```

How can I then use JavaScript to keep the name of the parameter and simply replace the `'&'` with `'&amp;'`?

Comment: you should probably be using [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) instead of a regex.

Comment: @jbabey: How is it relevant here? encodeURIComponent will do percentage encoding, while OP wants HTML entity encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex: `/&(?=[a-z]+=)/` and this replacement: `&amp;`

This uses a lookahead assertion rather than eating up the parameter name.

Comment: It will mangle numeric references like `&#39;` and will miss character references with digits like `&frac12;`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a URL which might be partially encoded in HTML, and you're trying to make a best effort at producing XHTML validating textarea content, then you can use the [list of HTML character references](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/entities.json) to identify ampersands which are not part of an HTML character reference:

```
str.replace(/&(?!#(?:[0-9]|[xX][0-9A-Fa-f])|lt;|gt;|amp|...)/g, '&amp;')
```

where ... is replaced with the set of entities from that list that you care to recognize.

Note that most of those character references end in semicolon, so are not allowed to be followed immediately by an equals sign, so are not ambiguous with URL parameters.  Only certain entities can appear without a semicolon for backwards compatibility.

If you don't care about validating, then you can just let the browser take care of it by ensuring that your URL doesn't contain the substring `</textarea` by doing something like

```
str.replace(/</g, '%3c')
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from lookahead assert, you can also use a backreference:

```
var regex = /&([a-z]+)=/gi;
str = str.replace(/&([a-z]+)=/gi,'&amp;$1');
```

When `$n` appears in the replace string, it will be replaced by the n'th parenthesized pattern in the regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Who needs regex when you've got jQuery `html()`.  Especially since you've got a `jquery` tag on your question :D

What this does is leverage  the browser's `innerHTML` property. see [api](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/ZtBy3/)

```
var str = 'http://www.somesite.com/id/2343?paramA=1&paramB=asd';
$('#test-box').text(str);
$('#html-box').text($('#test-box').html());
```